# Can I safely rename/move a dll that is already loaded by a process?

Tags: windows, dll

I have a dll that is loaded and file-locked by a process, and I would like to update it with a newer version. I'm looking for an alternative to terminating the process to release the file lock before updating the dll. It is okay that the existing live processes still uses the old version, as long as newly instantiated ones pick up the new logic.

It seems that I can simply rename/move the dll and the live process still seems to work well. Is it safe to do this? If the dll's code has already been loaded into the process then why does it still need to lock the dll?

Comment: I am positively sure that this is not possible at all under Windows. Unix will let you replace an executable (including shared library) when it's loaded, but this works because the OS lies to you (it really keeps the original file but without any link, and your new version will be visible via a link). Windows, on the other hand, will simply not allow you to open the file for writing. This makes sense too, since in practically every possible situation, it is _not at all_ "OK" to do such a thing.

Answer (score 3):

It is not always ok to move all dll's used by any random application.  Some applications, like asp.net, use a shadow copy concept where they actually copy the dll and use the copy leaving you free to modify the original.  In the case of asp.net, if you modify the original asp.net will automatically spool up a new app domain using the new dll and gracefully shut down the old one.

If the application you're referring to has a lock on the dll, then you can't safely change it.

Comment: If the application has a lock on the DLL you can't change it at all!

Comment: Sam - thanks for highlighting the shadow copy concept, I think my problem is more specific in that the process I am interested in doesn't use shadow copy, so I would like to understand why it is not safe to change it?

Comment: EJP - I tested that my application locks the dll using Process Explorer, but I can still move the locked dll somewhere else. When I then copy in a new version, I can start a new instance of my application and verify that it uses the new version. i.e. using this method I can have two application instances running different versions of the underlying dll. Wonder what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your dll/application. For example, dll may use shared memory, or implement inter-process communication. New dll version may implement it differently. So once new instance will start, you'll have two conflicting versions in memory. 
So it's not safe in general case, though in your particular case it may be OK.